# Cell Phone Monitor in J2SE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, mobile, monitoring, bluetooth

Need an incoming cell phone call monitoring in my application. In realtime.
Java Application is running at PC (Linux or Windows).
There is a connection PC to cell phone over serial cable or bluetooth.

How to implement monitoring? Are there any frameworks that provide high level interface to major mobile systems (nokia, SE, motorola, siemens) without need to write AT-commands?

Are there something like Gnokii or Wammu for Java or bindings for them?
Are there some proprietary solutions from mobile vendors? Interested in Java solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java Telephony API (JTAPI)

XTAPI: http://xtapi.sourceforge.net/ is one of its implementation

I have personal experience developing application with XTAPI and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a serial cable connected to the phone,your java app can just listen on the serial port for incoming call indication (RING) from the phone.Javax.comm and RxTx are the serial port libraries available for java.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [SMSLib](http://smslib.org/) project. The api has several callback methods for SMS and Call events. It is a high level implementation on top of the RxTx library if I remember correctly.